# RelativeLayout change height in onGlobalLayout and leave width to fill

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have the following ListView-item:
[image]

Currently everything works as intended and is placed where it should, except for the width of the TextView (2).

Since I use a RelativeLayout with some wrap_contents, I use a onGlobalLayoutListener so I can access the MeasuredWidths and Heights the moment the View is done loading and rendering. With the TextView2 however I get some weird results when I debug.

The first time onGlobalLayout is called, measuredWidth of the TextView2 is what it should be (375 px). The second time however, it's 48 px (same as the Height) and when I look at the fields of the TextView2 it says: `mMeasuredHeight: 375; mMeasuredWidth: 48` :S

My layout is at the bottom of this post. My onGlobalLayoutListener is:

```
if(view.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()){
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        // This will be called once the layout is finished, prior to displaying it
        // So we can change some widths and heights based on other View-Elements that are filled now
        // (We couldn't do this in the XML itself since they weren't filled yet and we didn't knew the sizes yet.)
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(holder != null){
                ...

                // Change the height of the ProductName-TextView to match the Image and leave the width as is
                int height = h.imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
                int width = h.tvName.getMeasuredWidth();
           *    h.tvName.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(h.imageView.getMeasuredHeight(), h.tvName.getMeasuredWidth()));

                ...
            }

            // Since we don't want onGlobalLayout to continue forever, we remove the Listener here again.
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

The `*` is a breakpoint. The first time width is 48 and height is 375. The second time width is 48 and height is 48, and if I look at the mMeasuredHeight and mMeasuredWidth fields in my holder.textView2, they are h=375 and w=48 :S

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@layout/transparent_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/checkbox_content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/filler_space_image"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_ll"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_ll"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_result_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_product_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_ll"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actv_result_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_ll"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/et_result_amount"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_product_name"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tags"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_result_amount"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_ll"
        android:text="@string/tags"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/actv_result_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_tags"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_ll"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/right_ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/filler_space_price"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_tags"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_tags_content_description"
            android:background="@layout/transparent_background"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Going back to the layout you're trying to achieve, it appears that the `ImageView` can vary in size and you want to change the height of the `TextView` to match it? Have you tried putting the top row of Views in a `LinearLayout` with `android:gravity="centerVertical"`? Centering the `TextView` will have the same effect as increasing the height. Another thing to consider is how the list will look with varying image sizes, it may look better to force them all to be consistent by setting a width, height and scaleType? Basically I think there's an easier solution to this.

Comment: @darnmason I used to have three nested LineairLayouts to create the same result, but since there were more things I had to add (in the picture provided I had to add the ImageButton 8), I decided to use a RelativeLayout for the entire item for better performance. The Image varies per device size. So to get the width of the Space 9 and the height of the TextView 2 and 3 the same, I use the onGlobalLayout. The width of the TextView 2 I want to keep at wrap_content (with leftOf left_ll & rightOf right_ll). If it's then to big to fit, it should fill & show the `ellipsize="end" (3 dots).

Comment: The problem with RelativeLayout however, is to use leftOf / rightOf / etc. and match sizes, the View has to be loaded and LayoutParams for the size and margins should be used to correct some of them to match and give the result I want in the picture. I just don't understand why it's giving 48 as width, while it is clearly 375.

Comment: I still think you're overdoing it, for example you don't need `Space` widgets, you could lose the `LinearLayout`s and markup 4 toRightOf 1, 6 toRightOf 1, 5 toLeftOf 3, 7 toLeftOf 3 and the gaps will work themselves out. Then use alignTop and alignBottom to get TextViews to match the height of the image...

Comment: But yeah I don't understand either why the width of the TextView is wrong in the layout listener.

Comment: @darnmason Ah ok, I used the Spaces when I had the LineairLayouts and used weights, but you're indeed right I could just remove them. I'll start by doing that, though I still find it odd that the TextView2's width are changed like that in the onGlobalLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was (after I figured it out) pretty obvious.. Instead of

```
h.tvName.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    h.imageView.getMeasuredHeight(), h.tvName.getMeasuredWidth()));
```

I now use

```
h.tvName.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    h.tvName.getMeasuredWidth(), hh.imageView.getMeasuredHeight()));
```

Difference you ask? I used `LayoutParams(height, width)` instead of `LayoutParams(width, height)`...